# GeocodeAddressAsync is throwing a NSErrorException on some addresses but not all

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, geolocation, core-location

Has anyone had issues when using Xamarin to parse location strings?

Eg. I'm passing the address "Buffalo, NY 14267" into MonoTouch.CoreLocation.CLGeocoder.GeocodeAddressAsync() which then throws an unuseful exception.

However if I use an address like "Addison, TX 75001" then there is no error.

The code is simply:

```
CLPlacemark[] placemarks = await _geoCoder.GeocodeAddressAsync(new CLLocation((double)location.Latitude, (double)location.Longitude));
```

EDIT: I am using **GeocodeAddressAsync** not **ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync**

Comment: What's the "unuseful" exception? Have you had a look at possible inner exceptions? Your example code is wrong. You pasted the reverse one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting an `NSErrorException` from `ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync` **OR** `GeocodeAddressAsync` then I would **assume** you are suppling a bad longitude or/and latitude or bad address and getting a domain = `kCLErrorDomain` and `code` = 8 and thus Apple has no data regarding your request.

#### From `CLError.h`, code = 8 is:

```
kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult,  // A geocode request yielded no result
```

Try/Catch on `NSErrorException` and determine the domain/code of the error:

#### Example:

```
try
{
    var _geoCoder = new CLGeocoder();
    var placemarks = await _geoCoder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(new CLLocation(42.885441, -78.878471));
    foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(placemark.ToString());
    }
    placemarks = await _geoCoder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(new CLLocation(232.965158, -96.876839));
    foreach (var placemark in placemarks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(placemark.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is Foundation.NSErrorException)
{
    var nsErrorException = ex as Foundation.NSErrorException;
    Console.WriteLine($"{nsErrorException.Domain}:{nsErrorException.Code}");
}
```

#### Output:

```
50 Delaware Ave, 50 Delaware Ave, Buffalo, NY  14202, United States @ <+42.88550930,-78.87880640> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+42.88550930,-78.87880640> radius 70.84', center:<+42.88550930,-78.87880640>, radius:70.84m)
kCLErrorDomain:8
```

Comment: I made a typo in the original question: I am using GeocodeAddressAsync  not ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync

Comment: @msmt Either way, try/catch the same way as in my example and check what the domain/code is in the `NSErrorException`, your answer to the underlaying problem that `GeocodeAddressAsync` is having will be there.

Comment: @msmt I'm assuming you will get the same result (`kCLErrorDomain`:`8` as zip code 14267 has zero businesses, single-family and multi-family addresses registered with the post-office and thus Apple has zero data for it also. Try Buffalo, NY 14202 instead.... I updated my answer with the code=8 Objective-C enum description from `CLError.h`

Comment: you are correct. I'm getting the error code 8. This is the first time I'm doing any real geolocation work so do you have any recommendations to fallback on when a geolocation fails? Any best practices (eg. if 14267 does not work then recommend another close location...)

Comment: @msmt You definitely have to defensively code for times that you get zero results from Apple, Google, other 3rd-party services, it is going to happen as you have seen first hand, the issue becomes a user experience that only you can answer in terms of what/how do you present to the user in that case. Do you know the address is City, ST, Zip, can you remove the zip? It you can you remove the zip and city, etc... Also Zipcode areas can be huge(!) in some states, can you add a street, intersection, landmark, etc... Were are you sourcing that address from, can the user add more info upon failure?

Comment: Thanks for these tips, I'll keep them in mind as I explore solutions to my issue. Again, thanks for all your help... much, much appreciated.